Didn't understand relationship 'UserOrGroup' in field path
I am querying the GroupMember object and inside my query I'm trying to get the related Email field value from the UserOrGroupId relational field, here is my query:
SELECT Id, GroupId, Group.Name, UserOrGroupId, UserOrGroup.Email 
FROM GroupMember 
WHERE GroupId In :leadQueueIdSet

This query is working in my sandboxes, but it is getting error in my Production environment.
Here is the error I'm getting:

GroupId, Group.Name, UserOrGroupId, UserOrGroup.Email FROM GroupMember ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:48 Didn't understand relationship 'UserOrGroup' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.


The error you are encountering in your Salesforce query is due to the polymorphic nature of the UserOrGroupId field in the GroupMember object. This field can reference either a User or a Group, and standard SOQL does not support direct field access on polymorphic fields.
Refer to this Question - Selection of group name and user name from GroupMember in one query

Thank you @Josyula
